# creating a python dictionary like object from protocol buffers for use in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, protocol-buffers

I currently interface to a server that provides protocol buffers.  I can potentially receive a very large number of messages.  Currently my process to read the protocol buffers and convert them to a Pandas DataFrame (not a necessary step in general, but Pandas offers nice tools for analyzing datasets) is:

1. Read protocol buffer, it will be a google protobuf object
2. Convert protocol buffers to dictionary using [protobuf_to_dict](https://github.com/benhodgson/protobuf-to-dict)
3. use `pandas.DataFrame.from_records` to get a DataFrame

This works great, but, given the large number of messages I read from the protobuf, it is quite inefficient to convert to dictionary and then to pandas.  My question is: is it possible to make a class that can make a python protobuf object look like a dictionary?  That is, remove step 2.  Any references or pseudocode would be helpful.

Comment: But `Convert protocol buffers to dictionary` makes a python protobuf object look like a dictionary ;) You rather need some `pandas.DataFrame.from_protbuf` but I don't know answer for this problem.

Comment: I looked at the code, it definitely does *not* look like it's wrapping the protobuf object, but rather creates a real new dictionary. I believe @Justin is looking for something that only wraps, without copying data.

Comment: Yes, I'd would like to make the google protobuf object look like a dictionary rather than copying the data to python dict first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check the [ProtoText](https://github.com/XericZephyr/prototext) python package. 
It does provide in-place dict-like operation to access your protobuf object.

Example usage: 
Assume you have a python protobuf object `person_obj`.

```
import ProtoText
print person_obj['name']       # print out the person_obj.name 
person_obj['name'] = 'David'   # set the attribute 'name' to 'David'
# again set the attribute 'name' to 'David' but in batch mode
person_obj.update({'name': 'David'})
print ('name' in person_obj)  # print whether the 'name' attribute is set in person_obj 
# the 'in' operator is better than the google implementation HasField function 
# in the sense that it won't raise Exception even if the field is not defined
```